# Python, scipy: Key Error in the generation of a Voronoi Tesselation

Tags: python, spatial, voronoi, tesselation

In generating Voronoi Tesselations from a set of lat/lon points, I am getting an error that seems to occur when a certain point is used as part of the inputs.

To isolate the problem, I removed and added these points into the input one by one, and found the error to be exactly reproducible when the "PROBLEM POINT" is added back.

```
ip = [[31.249566 , 30.0458139],
       [31.2496667, 30.0460511],
       [31.2497362, 30.0462148],
       [31.2498083, 30.0463844],
       [31.2499063, 30.0466152],
       [31.2497861, 30.0457439],
       [31.2493217, 30.0458917],
       [31.249051 , 30.0459779],
       [31.2485747, 30.0461295],
       [31.2487919, 30.0460604],
       [31.2494149, 30.0461318],
       [31.2491506, 30.0462165],
       [31.249482 , 30.0463046],
       [31.2495479, 30.0464743],
       [31.2496453, 30.0467251],
       [31.2488556, 30.0467515],
       [31.2489719, 30.047009 ],
       [31.2493148, 30.0466096],
       [31.2492253, 30.0463954],
       [31.2492947, 30.0465617],
       [31.2494044, 30.0468267],
       [31.2497576, 30.0466778],
       [31.2500132, 30.0465702], # PROBLEM POINT
       [31.2495429, 30.0470592],
       [31.2497817, 30.0474367],
       [31.2490658, 30.0472466]]
```

Code:

```
import libpysal
from libpysal.cg.voronoi  import voronoi, voronoi_frames
regions_s, vertices_s = voronoi(ip)
```

Error Trace:

```
libpysal/cg/voronoi.py in voronoi_regions(vor, radius)
     97             continue
     98 
---> 99         ridges = all_ridges[p1]
    100         new_region = [v for v in vertices if v >= 0]
    101 

KeyError: 5
```

What could be happening here? For context, these are all projected points ("EPSG:4326") in Egypt, and I have made sure there are no duplicates. Under the hood, the library uses scipy.
`from scipy.spatial import Voronoi`

Comment: This doesn't throw any errors in my environment (using libpysal 4.6.2 and scipy 1.6.1).